# Make multiple dictionaries of multiple matrices using a loop function in python

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix

I need to make 11 dictionaries of 100 (N,N) Matrices each. I want to make a loop function to define all of these

```
A1={}
for x in range(1,101):
    R = np.random.random((1,1))
    A1["{0}".format(x)] = np.dot(R,R.transpose())/2

A2={}
for x in range(1,101):
    R = np.random.random((2,2))
    A2["{0}".format(x)] = np.dot(R,R.transpose())/2

A3={}
for x in range(1,101):
    R = np.random.random((3,3))
    A3["{0}".format(x)] = np.dot(R,R.transpose())/2
```

at once.
I tried to do it like this but it didn't work.

```
for k in range(1,11):
A"%s"%k={}
for x in range(1,101):
    R = np.random.random((k,k))
    A"%s"%k["{0}".format(x)] = np.dot(R,R.transpose())/2
```

The important part is that A3 had 3 by 3 matrices, A5 has 5 by 5 matrices, etc.

Comment: You can't declare variables using string formatting. Consider putting your dictionaries in a list instead

Comment: Since each of the loops are over the exact same range, just put all the bodies inside one loop!

Comment: Also, you can just use `str(x)` instead of `"{0}".format(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dynamically create variable names. Try something like:

```
containing_dict = {}
for k in range(1, 11):
    key = 'A{}'.format(k)
    containing_dict[key] = {}
    for x in range(1, 101):
        R = np.random.random((k,k))
        containing_dict[key][x] = np.dot(R,R.transpose())/2
```